# JSON Array Parsing multiple array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

i have this fragment of JSON code that i want to parse: basically i want to store the "effective time" and "purpose", that you can see inside the "results" json array using Java(Android Studio), but i'm struggling doing it as it's my first time dealing with JSON.

```
 {
      "results": [
        {
          "effective_time": "20121114",
          "inactive_ingredient": [
            "Inactive ingredients *acetylated monoglycerides, *anhydrous lactose, *carnauba wax, colloidal silicon dioxide,*corn starch, *croscarmellose sodium, D&C Yellow #10 Aluminum Lake, FD&C Yellow #6 Aluminum Lake, hypromellose, *hypromellose phthalate, *iron oxide Yellow (iron oxide ochre), methacrylic acid copolymer, microcrystalline cellulose, *mineral oil, *polyethylene glycol (PEG)-400, *polysorbate 80, povidone, pregelatinized starch, *propylene glycol, *simethicone, silicon dioxide, sodium bicarbonate, sodium hydroxide, sodium lauryl sulfate, starch, stearic acid, talc, titanium dioxide, triacetin, and triethyl citrate. *May also contain."
          ],
          "purpose": [
            "Purpose Pain reliever"
          ],
          "keep_out_of_reach_of_children": [
            "Keep out of reach of children In case of overdose, get medical help or contact a Poison Control Center right away."
          ]
              ...
              ...
        }
       ]
 }
```

this is my code so far

```
String drugDescription="no description";
try{
    JSONObject jsonQueryResult = new JSONObject(JSONFILE);
        JSONArray jsonResultArray = jsonQueryResult.getJSONArray("result");
        JSONObject jsonDrugDescription = jsonResultArray.getJSONObject(0);
        drugDescription = jsonDrugDescription.toString();
}
catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
searchResultTextView.setText(drugDescription);
```

drugDescription is still showing "no description"

thank you for the help!

Comment: Check whether you get any exception in the catch block. Put a log statement in your catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are new you should go through some tutorial on Json parsing [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-json-parsing-tutorial).

For getting the `effective_time` and `purpose` you can do as:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray firstResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        if (firstResult != null && firstResult.length() > 0) {
            for (int i=0; i<firstResult.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject result = firstResult.getJSONObject(i);
                // This is your effective_time; 
                String effective_time = result.getString("effective_time"); 
                JSONArray purpose = result.getJSONArray("purpose");
                if (purpose != null && purpose.length() > 0) {
                    for (int j=0; j<purpose.length(); j++) {
                        // This is the purpose;
                        String purposeData = purpose.getString(j); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i tried something similar before postin, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then you probably don't have the json that you have posted.

Comment: it's that one, because if i try with other parts of the json that don't start with a jsonarray, i can make it work; it's accessing the result array that makes me struggle

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Does it show any error? Did you debug and see what happen ?

Comment: i mean that when i set a text view with drugDescription it shows me "no description", the initial value of the variable

Comment: You need to post more code where you are setting the TextView, so that I can see

Comment: i added that line of code, but i assure you that everything it's working fine without jsonarray

Comment: Can you post the updated code (code which I have posted) ? What do you see debugging with break point?

Comment: i solved! thank you for your code, it's right, i just forgot to change drugDescription's value using new ahahahahha